# Shopping cart simulator

Tags: javascript, angular.js, e-commerce

I have tried to simulate a cart (only partially completed). I just wanted to see how the code upto this point can be enhanced. I am trying to learn about the usage of `directive`s.

Here I have used 2 directives:

1. `msgpallette`- to show the messages when something is added to the cart
2. `item-container` - to show each item in menu

A demo of the same is provided at [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLJos5CrqlJ8QNRFAtqu?p=preview)

Do tell me whether I have used directives properly. If not, do suggest code changes with explanations.

**HTML**

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id="msger">
    <msgpallete msg="message" ng-show='show'>{{message}}
    </msgpallete>
</div>
<p ng-repeat = "item in items">
    <item-container
        startcounter = 1 
        resetter     = 'reset'
        name         = {{item.name}} >
        {{item.name}}
    </item-container><br><br>
</p>
<p ng-repeat = "order in orders">
    <order-container >
        {{order.name}}
    </order-container><br><br>
</p>
</body>
```

**JS**

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.items = [
  {'name':'kabab'},
  {'name':'noodles'},
  {'name':'chicken'},
  {'name':'egg'}
  ]      
  $scope.resettrigger = function () {   
  $scope.reset = true;
  $timeout(function() {
  $scope.reset = false; 
},100)
}
  $scope.show=0;
  $scope.addMsg = function (qty,item) {
  $timeout.cancel($scope.promise);
  $scope.show = true;
  msg = "Added "+qty+" "+item+" to the cart";
  $scope.message = msg;
  $scope.promise = $timeout(function() {
  $scope.show = false; 
},3000)

}})
.directive('msgpallete',function(){
 return{

restrict:"E",
transclude:true,
scope:{},
template:"<h4 ng-transclude ></h4>"
}
})

.directive('itemContainer',function(){
return {
controller: function() {return {}},
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{

  resetter:"="
    },
transclude:true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){

        scope.qty = attr.startcounter
        scope.add = function(){

            scope.qty++;
        }
        scope.remove = function(){
            scope.qty--;
        }
        scope.reset = function(){
    console.log("attr.item:"+attr.name);
     scope.$parent.addOrder(attr.name)
    scope.$parent.addMsg(scope.qty,attr.name)
    console.log("value when submitted:" + scope.qty + "name:"+ attr.name);
            scope.qty = attr.startcounter;
            scope.$parent.resettrigger();
        }

        scope.$watch(function(attr){
            return attr.resetter
        },
        function(newValue){
            if(newValue === true){
                scope.qty = attr.startcounter;
            }
        });


    },
    template:"<button ng-click='reset();'>Add to cart</button>&nbsp&nbsp"+            
         "<button ng-click='remove();' >-</button>&nbsp"+
                 "{{qty}}&nbsp" +
                 "<button ng-click='add();'>+</button>&nbsp&nbsp"+
         "<a ng-transclude> </a>"


    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't have time for a full review but hopefully this will give you some food for thought.

Why add an extra variable `show`? Angular is more than capable of binding to an expression:

```
ng-show='message != ""'
```

Then you have one less thing to juggle in your controller:

```
$scope.addMsg = function (qty, item) {
    $scope.message = "Added " + qty + " " + item + " to the cart";
    // console.log($scope.message); // if you want to debug
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.message = ""; 
    },3000);
}
```

Some notes about code clarity:

- Don't forget your semicolons
- Add some spacing between operators e.g. `a + b + c + d` is easier to read than `a+b+c+d`
- `addCartMessage` is probably more descriptive than `addMsg`

As for your question about directives:

`msgpallete` should be killed with fire
`itemContainer` seems like a good candidate but execution isn't great (will come back to this if I get time)

By removing the `msgpallete` directive you can change your view to:

```
<div id="msger">
    <h4 ng-show='message != ""'>{{message}}</h4>
</div>
```

(Your controller will be unchanged).